# Зацикливание вызова callback в telegram боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, callback, бот, inline

Столкнулся с проблемой, что при нажатии любой кнопки inline-клавиатуры `telegram` бота выбранная кнопка как будто залипает. То есть после нажатия, действие отрабатывается и всё хорошо – бот переходит в режим ожидания команды. Но через некоторое время (произвольное) нажатие повторяется циклично, хотя я уже ничего не нажимаю. Бот написан на `python 3.6`. Библиотека `GitHub - pyTelegramBotAPI`

Вот клавиатура:

```
def choose_film_markup(button=config.vote_films):
    markup_choose_film = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    btn_in_film1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=(button[0]['film_name'] + ' - ' + str(button[0]['rate'])), callback_data='film1')
    btn_in_film2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=(button[1]['film_name'] + ' - ' + str(button[1]['rate'])), callback_data='film2')
    btn_in_film3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=(button[2]['film_name'] + ' - ' + str(button[2]['rate'])), callback_data='film3')
    markup_choose_film.add(btn_in_film1, btn_in_film2, btn_in_film3)
    return markup_choose_film
```

Обработчик callback-ов:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: c.data)
def choose_film(c):

film_rates = functions.read_film_rates_with_id(1)

if c.data == 'film1':
    if c.from_user.id not in film_rates[1]['user_ids'] and c.from_user.id not in film_rates[2]['user_ids']:
        if c.from_user.id in film_rates[0]['user_ids']:
            film_rates[0]['user_ids'].remove(c.from_user.id)
            film_rates[0]['rate'] -= 1
            print(film_rates)
        else:
            film_rates[0]['user_ids'].append(c.from_user.id)
            film_rates[0]['rate'] += 1
            print(film_rates)

elif c.data == 'film2':
    if c.from_user.id not in film_rates[0]['user_ids'] and c.from_user.id not in film_rates[2]['user_ids']:
        if c.from_user.id in film_rates[1]['user_ids']:
            film_rates[1]['user_ids'].remove(c.from_user.id)
            film_rates[1]['rate'] -= 1
            print(film_rates)
        else:
            film_rates[1]['user_ids'].append(c.from_user.id)
            film_rates[1]['rate'] += 1
            print(film_rates)

elif c.data == 'film3':
    if c.from_user.id not in film_rates[1]['user_ids'] and c.from_user.id not in film_rates[0]['user_ids']:
        if c.from_user.id in film_rates[2]['user_ids']:
            film_rates[2]['user_ids'].remove(c.from_user.id)
            film_rates[2]['rate'] -= 1
            print(film_rates)
        else:
            film_rates[2]['user_ids'].append(c.from_user.id)
            film_rates[2]['rate'] += 1
            print(film_rates)

functions.write_film_rates_with_id(film_rates)

bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=c.message.chat.id,
                      text='Ваш выбор?',
                      message_id=c.message.message_id,
                      reply_markup=choose_film_markup(film_rates))
```

Comment: Такая же ситуация возникла сегодня (по крайней мере я ее заметил). Нажатие на кнопку было обработано корректно, но с очередным запросом getUpdates получаю дополнительные ответы, как будто на кнопку нажал несколько раз. Получил порядка 20-30 ответов. Проверил в паре других ботах - похожая ситуация. В одном случае зарегистрировано было 3-х кратное нажатие; в другом - 2-х кратное. До этого момента код работал исправно и никаких изменений в него не вносилось. Через 1-2 часа ситуация нормализовалась. Предположу что какие-то "махинации" у самого Telegram

Answer (score 0):

Товарищи, весь день боролся с этой проблемой!!! Нигде не мог найти решения данной проблемы, потом бац, под ночь уже, на хабре нашел [статейку](https://habrahabr.ru/post/335886/). Вся суть в том, что на CallBack нужно дать ответ; у каждого CallBack есть свой id, и пока ты не ответишь на него с помощью bot.[answerCallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery), указав id того CallBack на который отвечаешь, он будет "напоминать и напоминать" о себе.

Пример (в первой ссылке, на хабр, немного нагляднее наверное, чем у меня):

```Python
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:c.data)
def inlin(c):
    soobshenie = c.data
    soobshenie_slova = re.split(r'[\s]',soobshenie)
    print(soobshenie_slova)
    if soobshenie_slova[0] == 'Удалить':
        k_b_2 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
        k_b_2.one_time_keyboard = True
        b1_2 = telebot.types.KeyboardButton(text='Отмена')
        b2_2 = telebot.types.KeyboardButton(text='Удалить')
        k_b_2.row(b1_2, b2_2)
        bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Вы уверены, что хотите удалить запись?', reply_markup=k_b_2)
        global curok
        global iid
        global chatiid
        curok = 1
        iid = soobshenie_slova[1]
        chatiid = c.message.chat.id
        bot.answer_callback_query(c.id, text="")
    elif soobshenie_slova[0] == 'Редактировать':
        print('Нажали Редактировать')
    return ()
```

Даже с пустым параметром `text` можно.

**Нет смысла пытаться разобрать весь мой код... Суть: мы получили CallBack, обработали информацию, которую он нам нес, и сообщили телеграмму, что мы обработали этот CallBack (4-ая строчка снизу).**

Ребят, ну у меня работает теперь, крч.